# Why is Java the lingua franca at so many institutions?

Tags: programming-languages, education

**EDIT: This question at first seems to be bashing Java, and I guess at this point it is a bit. However, the bigger point I am trying to make is why any one single language is chosen as the one end all be all solution to all problems. Java happens to be the one that's used so that's the one I had to beat on here, but I'm not intentionality ripping Java a new one :)**

I don't like Java in most academic settings. I'm not saying the language itself is bad -- it has several extremely desirable aspects, most importantly the ability to run without recompilation on most any platform. Nothing wrong with using the language for Your Next App ^TM. (Not something I would personally do, but that's more because I have less experience with it, rather than it's design being poor)

I think it is a waste that high level CS courses are taught using Java as a language. Too many of my co-students cannot program worth a damn, because they don't know how to work in a non-garbage-collected world. They don't fundamentally understand the machines they are programming for. When someone can work outside of a garbage collected world, they can work inside of one, but not vice versa. GC is a tool, not a crutch. But the way it is used to teach computer science students is a as a crutch.

Computer science should not teach an entire suite of courses tailored to a single language. Students leave with the idea that all good design is idiomatic Java design, and that Object Oriented Design is the ONE TRUE WAY THAT IS THE ONLY WAY THINGS CAN BE DONE. Other languages, at least one of them not being a garbage collected language, should be used in teaching, in order to give the graduate a better understanding of the machines.

It is an embarrassment that somebody with a PHD in CS from a respected institution cannot program their way out of a paper bag.

What's worse, is that when I talk to those CS professors who actually do understand how things operate, they share feelings like this, that we're doing a disservice to our students by doing everything in Java. (Note that the above would be the same if I replaced it with any other language, generally using a single language is the problem, not Java itself)

In total, I feel I can no longer respect any kind of degree at all -- when I can't see those around me able to program their way out of fizzbuzz problems.

Why/how did it get to be this way?

Comment: The upside is that you will always be able to find a high paying job. Employers know that a lot of new graduates lack a lot of the fundamentals; the good ones can tell the difference between candidates.

Comment: I don't think universities is doing this. I am a student and we have used these languages in multiple courses: Standard ML, C, MIPS Assembler, Erland and Java.

Comment: Don't worry. Give Oracle half a chance and they will remedy the situation:)  Their lawsuits against Android and Apache are just the beginning of driving developers away. I teach at an institution that has taken the above as a cue to start teaching Python, in anticipation of the future market.

Comment: I think Joel said it best here - http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/ThePerilsofJavaSchools.html

Comment: @Jonas Me too. C, C++, Assembler, Java, C#, and a languages class.

Comment: @Michael: However, C++, C# and Java doesn't differ much. I hope you learn some functional programming in university too. We used Standard ML as first language-

Comment: @Jonas: Lisp count?

Comment: @Michael: Sure.

Comment: What academic settings are you referring to?  I don't offhand know anywhere where CSci students are expected to learn only one language.  (Last I was in school, you could have gotten by with C and Scheme, I think, if you picked your major and classes carefully, but you'd be using at least two dissimilar languages.)

Comment: It could be worse. Back in my day, the language for most CS classes was Pascal.

Comment: Can you explain how your L1 cache works? Can you design an ALU? Can  you explain Maxwell's equations? What about the thermodynamic properties of your motherboard? Could you build a USB drive? Do you REALLY know how your computer works? Or did you pick a level of abstraction appropriate for your interests and go from there?

Comment: @FranticPedantic: No. I don't see how that's relevant though.

Comment: Because deciding that you need to understand memory management to "fundamentally understand the machines they are programming for" is a completely arbitrary level to stop at. If it's not necessary to understand the problems you're interested in, your time is often better spent studying what you are interested in ( since nobody has enough time to learn everything ). And any argument you present as to why Java programmers need to learn memory management could be extended infinitely until everybody needs to know atomic physics to "understand" anything.

Comment: @Frantic: Actually, it's not arbitrary. It's the lowest level which is reasonably consistent across all architectures. Something like how a specific L1 cache works is only going to be useful in the context of a specific ISA and processor model. It's easy to explain Java concepts like references in terms of pointers and memory blocks, but it's impossible to do the reverse, because pointers are simply more powerful than references. In any case, my point here (which I've reiterated several times over) is that **no single language is sufficient for a sound education in Computer Science**. Period.

Comment: @Frantic: tl;dr; -> You can stop with the straw man argument now.

Comment: It's not even remotely a straw man argument - your position is that CS students should learn a lower level of abstraction and I'm noting that your argument could extend indefinitely. Maxwell's equations are actually far more consistent across architectures than C code is. Furthermore, levels lower than C code can not be explained with C code, so I'm not sure what you're getting at other than realizing that higher levels of abstraction intentionally conceal details of the lower level. And to say C is more powerful than Java is just formally wrong.

Comment: Furthermore if anyone has a straw man argument here it's you, given that I've never heard of a single CS program which only presents Java as a programming language.

Comment: @Frantic: My argument is that Java is not sufficient as a sole programming language for teaching CS. [You are taking my argument and blowing it out of proportion, and then arguing against that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man) -- that's what straw man is. As for Maxwell's equations, they're only useful for a specific problem domain. Understanding of memory is relevant to all problem domains. Anything lower level than C is also going to only be useful for a specific problem domain; a specific ISA.

Comment: I use C here because it's common, not because I think it's the perfect level of abstraction or what we should be using every day to write everything. But I do think that the knowledge of the machine necessary to use C correctly is essential for anyone in CS, even if they do spend their entire careers programming for the JVM or the CLR.

Comment: I've heard that TAMU switched its CPSC 111 course from Java to C++ after I graduated.  May have been Dr. Stroustrup's idea.

Comment: I did program in Java before I went to University and after years of studying and working as a developer I am happy that we started with Pascal instead of Java or C/C++ or Prolog/Haskell/Lisp (which came in later courses). I really liked Pascal to study programming concepts.

Comment: Sure its been said but I used Java, C, C++, Prolog, Scheme, R, and Python in my education...just in undergrad. sounds like someone needs a new school.

Comment: Can you point me to a computer science program or two that actually only teaches in Java? This isn't true of any of the program I'm familiar with, and I'm familiar with several.

Comment: I already commented but I'm going to add a little more. I helped teach an intro level CS course. More than once. The 2 worst devils in expressing programming concepts were pointers (C based course) and dynamic typing (python based course). Java has neither of those issues. Not to mention the compiler spits meaningful data which gcc (compiler franco in programming courses) does not. After 2 years of CS if you can't pick up another language, change your major. If your school doesn't give you the chance, change your school.

Comment: @Rig: Yes, those are difficult concepts. But they are *essential* concepts that any programmer are going to need. Pretending like they don't exist for a while causes damage (IMHO) in the long run.

Comment: @BillyONeal But do you really need to pick those up while you are learning the essentials? Like flow of control, types, algorithms, etc?

Comment: @Rig: Yes. Pointers are just as basic as flow of control, and types. (And more basic than algorithms) Yes, students have a hard time with them. Just as students have trouble learning intergals; but nobody would let you teach a calc class without touching them. Pointers are a foundational concept; ignoring them early on leads to greater pain later (at least that I've seen).

Comment: At my university, they teach us C, Java, C++, PHP, Assembly, Prolog, Lisp and some C# :) .

Comment: Any CompSci university that only teaches C++, Java or C# is a crappy university anyway.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This isn't a Java problem, it's a teaching problem. Not knowing how to program is not a languages fault, it's the students fault. Same goes for all your issues, GC, basic machine knowledge, how things work "under the hood" so to speak.

Your major gripe about garbage collection throws me slightly. Unless you're doing C or C++ garbage collection is typically very good and not an issue. Would you rather they all learn assembly? Higher level languages that are strict are very useful for teaching. It gives you the flexibility of libraries, packages, and other niceties when you need it, without any of the confusing language "sugar" present in most other higher level languages (PHP, Ruby, Python, Perl).

Comment: I'm not saying that the higher level languages should not be taught. But I am saying that something lower level (on the order of C or Fortran or some other systems programming language) should be taught as well. (Going lower than C is less useful because below that level anything you learn there is going to be specific to a single machine architecture). I'm not saying that all CS grads should be great low level programmers. But I am saying that if confronted with a low level problem, they should not sputter and die, as all the students around me seem to do.

Comment: Note however that another higher level language would be fine too -- my gripe here is the teaching that **any** one language is the end all be all solution to all problems. No sane person writes an OS kernel in Perl, just as no sane person writes massive string processing code in C.

Comment: @Billy: Going lower then your initial learning level is hard. I find myself looking at C++ / C code and having a bit of a *fun* time wrapping my head around it. Don't expect miracles, but don't expect angels either. Programmers need to have drive, lacking that they will all *"sputter and die"* quite quickly no matter what level the problem is.

Comment: @Josh: I agree that it is difficult. However, one of the things that piece of paper you get at the end is supposed to indicate is that you are able to accomplish difficult things.

Comment: @Billy: Again, they teach one language to keep everything in inline and the same. Having a choice I probably wouldn't pick anything *but* Java. You aren't taught that Java is the solution to all problems, your taught how to solve problems with Java as a tool. Expanding that toolkit to more specialized tools (C, Perl, Python, etc) is something you can either (a) do on your own or (b) do after you get a job. I have not met one person in a CS course I would hire to work with me. I would have to teach them too much!

Comment: @Billy: See the last part of my previous comment on that.

Comment: @Josh: Fair enough, but IMHO formal exposure to **at least** one other programming environment should be a necessity to be given a CS degree. The degree doesn't say "I understand Java", it says, "I understand CS". The two are not the same, and you cannot achieve a full understanding of CS using Java (or for that matter, **any** language) alone. (BTW, +1)

Comment: @Billy: With that I **fully** agree. CS != Java, in fact CS is mostly theory, patterns, and design; Java is simply used to facilitate that learning. Exposure to similar or alternate techniques in different language would be a great idea.

Comment: @Billy: Disagree that assembly language is less useful; lots of stuff (interrupt handling, addressing modes, handling overflows, etc) transcends architectures.  It introduces stuff you simply can't get with higher-level languages.

Comment: @TMN: When I said "lower than C", I mean "a language lower level than C". Yes, students need a basic understanding of what makes the insides tick, and they're going to get that in some form of architecture course, which will probably use some form of assembler for demonstrations. That doesn't mean that the student needs to be able to write good code in assembler, merely enough to understand the concepts involved.

Comment: I would definitely rather they all learn assembly. Maybe not first, and certainly not as their only language, but any coder without a solid understanding of ASM for the platform they develop on is crippled.  A coder without a solid understanding of Java... is not.

Comment: @MasonWheeler What makes them crippled?

Comment: @JoshK: An inability to debug at low levels, and a greatly reduced ability to properly reason about the implications of the code they write.

Comment: I know programmers who only learnt Java and are scared by C++ or C because they have to use pointers. I do not know if someone who cannot program with pointers can be considered a real programmer: after all, all modern computers and runtimes are still based on a basic architecture involving registers, main memory, stack, heap. So I prefer to program in Java rather than in C++ (it is definitely easier to get things done if you do not have to bother about memory management) but I agree that teaching should definitely not be restricted to Java.

Comment: +1 For mentioning that Garbage Collection is a red herring here. Only learning imperative languages is the REAL problem (be it Java, C++ or C#).

Comment: @Giorgio I would consider someone who learned to program in a functional language without pointers as much of a "real programmer" than another guy who learned C. Both are "real programmers"; it's just that their expertise lies in different areas. Knowledge of pointers is not a requirement for "real" programming, just as knowing CPU registers isn't a requirement either.

Comment: Real programmers only use punchcards, anyway. Not this newfangled "C" thingy.

Comment: @Andres F: I am a big fan of functional languages (even though, unfortunately, I could never use any FL for a real project) but I think that even if you program in, say, Scheme or Haskell, you need to have at least a rough idea of how they are implemented (stack, heap, pointers, memory allocation, garbage collection) if you want to write efficient code. So, yes, you can be a good programmer without knowing about pointers, but IMO knowing about them will make you a better programmers.

Comment: I agree with the OP that Computer Science students need to understand the machines they're programming. Garbage collection is not acceptable in all problem domains. I worked on avionics software that couldn't allow GC because of real-time constraints (hell, you were only allowed to allocate memory during program initialization for safety/certification reasons!)

Answer (score 12):

Are universities *really* doing this? Or is this just a perception people get when they get a bad job interview candidate?

I got my CS degree 4 years ago and while Java was used in the intro classes, it was not particularly emphasized after that. Off the top of my head, the core required courses required you to learn Java, C, C++, SML (functional programming language), assembly, matlab and CAST (circuit description language). This doesn't take into account all the math and theoretical CS courses and of course, the half dozen elective CS courses that would have exposed you to a whole bunch more. From talking with friends at a number of different universities, it didn't sound like what they were doing was much different.

If there are universities solely teaching Java, then that is indeed a tragedy. Not because Java is bad, but because it is just one tool of many that should be available to a programmer. A developer who only knows Java is equivalent to a carpenter who only knows how to use a hammer. However, I have trouble believing that's really the case, at least for respected universities. I suspect that this is just the perception from seeing bad candidates and blaming the school for the candidates' incompetence rather than the candidate's own lack of drive/motivation/curiosity/professionalism/etc.

Comment: Agreed. I just graduated a few years ago, and while most of my classes were taught using Java, it was hard to graduate without taking a class that was taught using C or C++, and we also had a programming language course that emphasized the use of Haskell.

Comment: In my degree we did Pascal first, then Java as our OO language. Past 2nd year though, 90% of profs didn't care what language you used. Some of us used c/c++/ruby/C#/python/even haskell, but most people stuck with what they knew, java. Only a handfull of courses required using assembly/c/c++ namely things like our 3D graphics (optional) course prettymuch enforced c/c++ for opengl. And obviously the basic systems course enforced SPARC assembly (because we were intentionally working & a low level). I hear they've moved to python/c++ in 1st year now though....

Answer (score 11):

I'm really surprised this is the situation as many schools.  When I got my CS degree, I had a series of languages courses that between them included all the popular languages of the day (this was almost 40 years ago): assembler (Univac 1108 and MIX), FORTRAN IV, SNOBOL4, COBOL, Lisp, and Algol 68.  I can't imagine having just one language being taught.  Or how I could appreciate what compilers had to do without having written some assembler programs.

We did use Algol and FORTRAN for most of the data and algorithms courses.  I would have liked to have spent more time with Lisp -- instead we had just an introduction and now am trying to re-learn some of the concepts.  We used SNOBOL4 for writing parsers -- and its pattern matching with backtracking built a good foundation for later work the regex libraries included with many modern languages.

This introduction to half a dozen languages sparked an interest in me that has continued ever since.

Answer (score 8):

To get the real reason, you would have to ask the people who run those institutions (and even then, they might not tell you).

Several *possible* reasons (and I'm neither defending nor accusing anyone here, just guessing):

**You can get things done in Java**

Java it is a general purpose language and as such can be used to solve a lot of problems.

**Lots of teachers understand Java**

It is difficult to teach a language that you don't understand

**Java is popular**

Which means that there are plenty of Java resources - books, an active community, code libraries etc.

**Java is easy**

You don't have to understand lots of low-level stuff or theory to do Java. You may not do it *well*, but at least you can get things done.

**Java is pervasive**

You can run it on more or less anything.

**There are jobs for Java programmers**

There are lots of jobs that need Java - teachers are supposed to be preparing students for the real world.

**There is limited time**

On many courses, there isn't time to teach multiple languages, theories, low-level concepts etc.

**It is what students want**

Lots of students have already heard of (and even used) Java. They like because it is familiar.

Answer (score 6):

That's what the industry asked for. There was a shortage of Java developers so schools starting creating them. Companies got developers who can start work as soon as they walked through the door.

Anyway, the language doesn't matter. They could teach a non-GC language and still produce bad programmers. The language schools use is an implementation detail. Schools should teach concepts. If this isn't the case then it's the school that is the problem not the language they teach with. Just because someone doesn't know what a pointer is doesn't mean they can't be an effective programmer.

GC is the way of the future anyway.

Comment: You don't need to know what a pointer is. But you need to be able to pick up the concept relatively quickly. Not being to understand pointers, or concepts similar to pointers, indicate lack of understanding of computer science as a whole. I'm not saying all CS grads need to be awesome low level programmers, but I'm saying they should at least have a conceptual understanding of what's going on when they receive a 4 year university degree.

Comment: CS isn't about programming.

Comment: @Javier: How is CS *not* about programming? Sure there's that branch of CS, "Theoretical Computer Science", which is not about programming, but for the most part it *is* about programming.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: the wikipedia definition is a little long, but the part that gets closest to programming is "the study of practical techniques for their implementation". that is, it's not about the implementation (programming) but studying the implementation techniques (algorithms, structures, languages, etc)

Comment: @Javier: I think "the study of programming" and "the action of programming" are one in the same. After all, code is read much more often than it is written. But that's beside the point -- when you receive a CS degree, the thing you're going to end up doing is programming.

Comment: "when you receive a CS degree, the thing you're going to end up doing is programming." that's part of the problem, and the reason why 'CS' graduates finish up knowing only about Java and nothing about science.

Comment: @Henry - *"That's what the industry asked for."* - that's a fallacy (one brought us by the good ol' dot-com.) As a Java developer, that is not true. 70% of new development is done in C and C++ (think about the little black chips in your toaster, microwaves, inside your car, your wireless router and your plasma tv.) The rest in the application space which is not all Java. Industrial numbers don't lie. Colleges have been perpetuating that lie (and screwing people up with their clueless M.O.) since the dot-com screw-up.

Comment: @BillyONeal It appears the "pointer"-concept is one of the hardest to model mentally, so it is indicative of being non-bad if you have.

Answer (score 5):

Laziness and profit motive. Java gets most people 80% of the way, with 20% of the effort. However, this often produces "monkey see monkey do" voodoo coders who don't have deep understanding of what is happening, and are unable to dig deeper than high-level tools.

Teaching C/C++ properly is difficult. Even when done well, quite a few won't fully understand low-level concepts like pointers (there are studies on this). Moreover, it does not seem immediately relevant in the job market.

Comment: But if yuo understand pointers, you can understand references much more easily.

Answer (score 3):

I mostly agree but to a certain degree.

If you are to teach CS cource focused on data structures or algorithms. Getting most of the unnecessary stuff out of the way is a good thing. You don't wan't students to deal with low level stuf when learning high level concepts.

On the other hand low level stuff should be also taught. Just so we get more all-around programmers.

Comment: I'm not talking about a single course. For a single course, that's fine. For an entire curriculum, it is not.

Answer (score 3):

As always it is a question of *what* you want to teach and how much time you have to do it in.

Doing things in Java means that you don't have to deal with stray pointers and free/malloc.  That means quite fewer hard-to-find bugs.

This doesn't mean that  you shouldn't learn about the underlying machine - which you must to be good at the trade - but that perhaps you should choose the right tool for the job.  High-level algorithms are perhaps not the best topic for the assembler course.

Comment: For an intro-to-programming course or a data structures course, Java is fine. Not for an entire 4-year curriculum however.

Comment: @Billy.  Agreed.  I am just mentioning that using Java buys you some things you do not have to worry about.  You should learn the basics in other courses without Java.

Answer (score 2):

Is it too much to ask that they be taught something about how computers really *work?* It makes no sense to me that any CS course outline would not include something of operating systems and computer archetecture. I'm not saying you should be able to design a computer on the back of an envelope, but a general overview puts all languages into perpective. I mean, Java runs in a *virtual machine!*

Comment: *Are* there good computer science programs that *don't* include an OS course and a computer organization course?

Comment: I certainly hope not!

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty I do not think that you should lose respect for all degrees and especially not CS because the only language taught is Java.

Any decent comp. sci student understands that his CS degree is nothing more than a piece of paper and that real knowledge will come from personal projects and personal study. I would like to think that the good students know they need to know C and learn how to get things done in Linux / Unix and learn how to NOT have their hand held by modern languages.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see a problem with using Java. The biggest problem (as you mentioned) is when universities teach imperative programming as the best and only way to solve all your problems. This is very far from the truth. For example instead of using three imperative languages (or even worst the same language) for three different courses, they should use three different programming paradigms. An example is Java (imperative), Prolog (declarative), and Haskell (functional).

As for why this happens, I think it's a combination of (1) politics - chairmen are not open minded or have personal benefits/sponsors, and (2) laziness - professors were once students and they teach whatever they know or like.

Answer (score -1):

Calvin college in Grand Rapids Mi.  Once they switched from Java to Python for introductory programming classes the professor in disbelief mentioned to a group of us near the end of his semester, "A lot of them can actually program, it's incredible".  His amazement was in contrast to the previous experiences with Java.  This doesn't make Java a bad language, just hard to pick up from scratch.  I would argue the same thing about C, or C++ or any language that requires intimate knowledge of memory allocation schemes or types.

Comment: Erm, Python requires intimate knowledge of types just like the other languages you mentioned.

Comment: I expect that languages with interpreters will be much easier to learn, since students can get feedback statement by statement rather than compile by compile.

Comment: @BillyONeal You misread me, The context was memory allocation in my last sentence.  I have yet to be concerned about the size or # of elements of a str() or dict() or tuple() or list() or set() ... I just 'use' them.

Comment: @kevincline  Thanks Kevin - this was what I was trying to get across.  Judging by the downvotes I need to work on my communication skills ;)

Answer (score -2):

I got a degree in computer systems engineering, so I did study assembly, microprocessors, VHDL, what the logic gates are and how to create a flip-flop out of them, I studied electrical circuits, operational amplifiers, low-pass filters, amplitude modulation, built a circuit in a lab that would sound like a telephone keypad, messed with a logic analyzer, took some physics classes. On the Linux side - I recompiled a kernel before, wrote a tiny device driver, and a homework file system.

But then I realized that I like more high-level stuff a lot more. I prefer Python over C. I like C# and I love the garbage collector. I like math and algorithms and data structures, but I am not a particular fan of pointers - I can mess with them; I just do not want to.

So, you think that the university should teach more C, less Java. Someone else thinks that they should teach everything in Scheme. Spolsky will take both.

Yes, it is true that a university degree is merely a piece of paper, but "do not let schooling get in the way of your education". There is always Wikipedia, Stack Overflow, Coursera.org, etc. Looks like the traditional universities will become less important.

If I could do undergrad all over, then I would have gone to a different school, I would not have studied any of the electrical engineering stuff, but rather Math, CS + minor in Physics and French. Scratch French; I should have studied abroad in Switzerland and learned 5 natural languages while at it. I would also go back and find a person who convinced me that I absolutely must take some intro to economics classes in college in order to survive it in the real world and smack him on the head with my collection of Milton Friedman's books (the only few books on the subject of economics that I read which do not suck). I also would not pay money for the book Freakonomics 1 or a book about Perl language.

In a hindsight, I would have done many things differently. All I can do now, and I recommend this to you, is choose your own adventure: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/choosing-your-own-adventure.html

Having hindsight I would have made 100 billion dollars on the stock market by now, and I would have invested it in cancer research, I would have hired scientists to rid the world of plastic waste; I would have donated enough cash to Ron Paul campaign so that the war in Middle East would be over 3 years ago.

Recognize now that you will never get your time back, so try to spend it wisely.

Comment: Downvoters, please elaborate.

Answer (score -2):

A few years ago I read somewhere that, in the UK, the Java decision was made to entice more students into programming. Apparently it was easier on the brain because of the lack of nasty pointers and memory management etc... I'd guess that this is the reason why Python is being quickly adopted as the new 'learning tool.' I'd be of the opinion that your typical uni course is not going to make you into a programmer. All it is meant to do is arm you with a certain amount of knowledge and prime you for programming. The day that one can call oneself a programmer generally comes a fair bit of time after uni and when that time comes, pointers, garbage collection and programming paradigms other than OOP, should not be a problem.

Answer (score -2):

Why is Java used?

Three reasons:

1. Java uses C-style syntax. Many programmers are familiar with it, so it reduces the learning curve.
2. Money was spent to market Java as cool and modern.  But compared to lisp, java is living in the stone age.
3. The JVM. JVM is the one cool thing about java that is legit, not just marketing hype. Although the JVM should be praised as a platform for running programs, it does not by itself merit the existence of the Java language.  You can theoretically and practically compile many different languages for the JVM.

Comment: Welcome.  This looks like if might be your first post to Stack Exchange Programmers.  Please take a look at the faq page http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq for some advice on reputation, asking and answering questions.  A key point is that answers should be informative, not provocative.  If you make an assertion like Java is stone age and Lisp is modern, explain why.  Many readers may know Lisp was specified in 1958 and is just slightly younger than FORTRAN.  If you want to say that something about Java that is shared with FORTRAN or Algol drives its design and limits it, describe it.

Answer (score -3):

Your question is supporting the findings of another person who wrote a paper saying Java is so cool but not heavy enough for scientific computing. I think he should just use Big Decimal with all its fine precisions, NANs etc..and get on with it.

I want to live only in a automatic garbage collected world. Its healthier, cleaner, neater, aesthetic, prevents money wasted on health expenses, is more desirable - don't have to tag something as unwanted - simply by dereferencing it or setting it to null or when I move out of scope the item gets automatically tagged for garbage collection..

Ok, now I am talking about Java only but it would be most helpful if this works in the real garbage scenario too. Java is write once run anywhere which is good enough for me for it to be used as a language in schools. No memory leaks and being liked by happy programmers who don't want to spend time tagging every object they use and stop using itself is good logic on behalf of Java.

Java has pointers - well we call them references.. 
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = "Hello";
String s3 = new String("Hello");

s1 and s2 will be pointing to the same String object - which is by reference
s1 == s2, s1.equals(s3) but s1 == s3 is false because s3 is a new reference object - this is java arithmetic of references and I understand all this so sorry, I do not wish to be labeled as someone who does not understand the under lying complexities of pointer arithmetic from C or C++.

Comment: References are not pointers. You can't use them arithmetically, and you can't use them to reinterpret a piece of memory to which they point. And of course, no matter how much you want to live in a garbage collected world, the fact of the matter is that the world is not a garbage collected world. I'm not saying that Java is a bad language, or that people shouldn't use java. If you like it, use it, there are things about it that are great. I just think it's inappropriate as a beginner language because it hides things that are essential for new programmers to understand.